# how do I getrid of geolocation

Tags: php, apache, geolocation

my server is hosted in Europe. my website scrapes title and description from other site which then includes into my core application which is in PHP. My problem is when accessing facebook and other geolocation enabled websites the desciption goes into location language.

How do I getrid of this?? is there any code is available in php?? or is it a server setting??

thanks

Mathew

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation is usually based on the IP address the request is coming from. Your options are:

- Proxy requests through another country
- Find a way to override the language on a per-site basis
- Move to a server in the country you want to appear to be from